# Simply Google Map view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

In my application I'd like to add Google Map with marked location, something like showing location of company for customers. What is the simpliest way to do that in Rails?

Comment: Checkout this link i hope this will help you out.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index#MarkerLocations

Comment: So, can I just paste link into my src= ? Should I install something else?

Comment: have you checked the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google map javascript in your html file and can show google map. Like an example if want to show map that show your current location in google map than please refer this link and you would get good example and can customize that javascript as your requirement. [geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) gem or [Google maps with rails](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-google-maps-rails/) for details map implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try this example for google map with Geolocation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  #map {
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

  function init() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400)
    };

    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
      position.coords.longitude);
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[1]) {
            map.setZoom(11);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
            });
            infowindow.setContent("Your location = " + results[1].formatted_address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

          } else {
            alert('No results found');
          }
        } else {
          alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
      }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(true);
      });
    } else {
      handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }

    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
      if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
      } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
      }

      var options = {
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105), 
        content: content
      };

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
      map.setCenter(options.position);
    }  
  }
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```